# BigQuery - lead function converts timestamp field to integer

Tags: google-bigquery

It seems like lead function (or any analytic function) on a timestamp field results in a column of type integer instead of a timestamp field.

```
select 
transaction,
  lead(time,1) over (order by time) nextTime,
  from [fh-bigquery:bigdataspain.aggr_transaction_clean]
  limit 1000
```

Is there any way to solve this without wrapping with another query?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in BigQuery, it loses type information in analytic functions. While it is getting fixed, the workaround is indeed to wrap with the following:

```
select transaction, usec_to_timestamp(nextTime) from (
select 
transaction,
  lead(time,1) over (order by time) nextTime,
  from [fh-bigquery:bigdataspain.aggr_transaction_clean]
  limit 1000)
```

Comment: Over three years later, this still hasn't been fixed. Strangely, I tried to replace `min(timestamp) over ()` by `first_value(timestamp) over (order by timestamp)`, but that still converts `timestamp` to an integer, even though it has no business doing that...

Comment: It is actually fixed - and I double checked original repro, it does return TIMESTAMP. Can you give example or jobid of query where you don't get TIMESTAMP type ?

Comment: The lead function works fine, and so does min used as an aggregate function, but not min used as a window function. jobid: job_qwZcuBLiFV0U_TIxIiBR0CB5bDY