# BigQuery: Coalesce converts TIMESTAMP to INTEGER

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm experiencing a problem with COALESCE function, when applied to TIMESTAMP field it converts it to INTEGER 
Here is the example

```
SELECT 
   c_date AS c_date,
   COALESCE(nd.c_datetime, od.c_datetime) AS c_datetime,
   COALESCE(nd.c_timestamp, od.c_timestamp) AS c_timestamp 
FROM [table1] as nd 
LEFT JOIN [table2] as od ON  nd.c_date = od.c_date ";
```

Though all 3 fields in both tables have TIMESTAMP type, query will return first one as TIMESTAMP, but  all the others will become INTEGER. Is this intended behaviour?

P.S. I found a workaround

```
 USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(COALESCE(nd.c_datetime, od.c_datetime)) AS c_datetime
```

but it's pretty strange that simple coalesce requires special actions to preserve type

P.P.S. I know that guys from Google are reading stackoverflow. The job id is job_vM_1Kxo4NBp5Ae3VmLmAI-4OXpo  . Hope it will help you!

Comment: It is definitely not specific to your given SELECT job. Try `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), COALESCE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NULL)` to see behavior you described. So it can be a bug

Comment: i think, similar bug was fixed last year for analytic fuctions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966756/bigquery-lead-function-converts-timestamp-field-to-integer/31967778#31967778 cc: @moshapasumanski

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yep, that query also reproduces this behavior. Hope this bug can be fixed soon.

Comment: Bug acknowledged - to get better tracking, it would help if you were to file it at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky Done, issue 479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop - this was a bug in legacy SQL reported in the tracker as https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=479 and since this bug has been fixed, so `COALESCE` preserves `TIMESTAMP` type.